# python Облачное хранилище mega permissionError

Tags: python, файлы, download

Проблема в том, что не могу скачать текстовый файл с хранилища. Вернее, он качается, но пустой из-за того, что выходит ошибка.

```py
from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()
m = mega.login("", "") # email, password

file = m.find("hotel.txt")
m.download(file)
```

Код такой, то есть просто скачать текстовый файл, но выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 791, in move
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\NIGGA2~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_r0z9_pji' -> 'hotel.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "MEGApy.py", line 8, in <module>
        m.download(file)
File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 564, in download
        return self._download_file(file_handle=None,
File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 745, in _download_file
        shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)
File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 812, in move
        os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\NIGGA2~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_r0z9_pji'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это баг библиотеки, который почему-то не фиксят.

1. Перейдите по пути `C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py` и откройте файл `mega.py`
2. Выше 745ой строки (`shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)`) вставьте это `temp_output_file.close()`
3. Сохраните изменения
4. Запускайте код